# Woocommerce: How to Update Payment Method

Tags: woocommerce, payment-gateway, payment-method

I'm on checkout page!
I've created a new payment gateway called "others", the user choose this gateway and a drop-down list with payment options such as "Visa, MasterCard, etc" becomes available.
When the user choose an option e.g.:"VISA", I want that the payment method title becomes "VISA", not "others".
I've try to use:

```
$order->set_payment_method_title($_POST[$this->id.'-admin-note']);
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone help me? Does someone know how to change the payment method title?

Comment: Yes, I'm tryng to use javascript to change title value. But I can't reach the object. If I use

Comment: $order->set_payment_method_title($_POST[$this->id.'-admin-note']);

Comment: It doesn't work. How can i change this value after the drop down is selected?
Al of these doesn't work:
$order->set_payment_method_title($_POST[$this->id.'-admin-note']);
$order->set_payment_method($_POST[$this->id.'-admin-note']);

Comment: But if I try to add a note it works:
$order->add_order_note(esc_html($_POST[ $this->id.'-admin-note']),1);

Comment: It's an example '$order' is the object.

Comment: I just need to change the payment method from a form, is that possible in Woo'shit'commerce?

Answer (score 0):

Hello this was the solution i found.

update_post_meta( $order_id, '_payment_method_title', 'Pay' );

Comment: Thanks Murilo,
It works perfectly.Thanks man.

Obrigado Murilo,
Funcionou perfeitamente, valew

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are two relevant order meta data fields:

- `_payment_method_title` is used in emails
- `'_payment_method` is the one displayed in the admin panel.

So you should probably update both. If you have the order object, you can do:

```
$order->update_meta_data('_payment_method', 'My payment method');
$order->update_meta_data('_payment_method_title', 'My payment method');
```